# When using a MaskedEditExtender of Masktype Time, how to Override an Undesirable Behavior?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, mask

The following two lines work fine when input is correctly specified:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MondayOpenTextBox" runat="server" MaxLength="5" />
<Ajax:MaskedEditExtender ID="MondayOpenMaskedEditExtender" runat="server" 
    TargetControlID="MondayOpenTextBox" AcceptAMPM="false" MaskType="Time" 
    Mask="99:99" />
```

If the user enters "12" then tabs to the next field, the minutes get populated with the current minute. This is not desirable for the page in question. I'd either like to popup an error message, or fill in "00" for the skipped digits.

This does not help:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="ValidateMondayOpenTextBox" 
    ControlToValidate="MondayOpenTextBox" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="X" 
    ValidationExpression="\d\d:\d\d" />
```

as the field is apparently formatted by the time the validator gets its turn at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `AutoComplete` property of your [MaskedEdit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx) extender to `false` in order to prevent it from filling the empty masked characters with the current time:

```
<Ajax:MaskedEditExtender ID="MondayOpenMaskedEditExtender" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="MondayOpenTextBox" AcceptAMPM="false" MaskType="Time"
    Mask="99:99" AutoComplete="False" />
```

That way, your validator should be able to properly do its job.

Answer (score 1):

To get it filled with :00 you can set the property AutoCompleteValue to "99:00"